# Matching up multiple Splines and Columns in Highcharts

Tags: html, highcharts

I have a chart that I want to be able to dynamically add columns, and a matching spline that will go over the top of that column.

Is there a way to make sure that they line up with each other?  By default splines get spaced in the middle of the xAxis label, and columns get spaced out dynamically.

I tried messing with the `pointPlacement` for the splines and that works to get them to line up with a column. BUT I can't figure out how to do that dynamically? I don't want to go in for 3,4,5,6,7... and so on numbers of series, and manually figure out what the pointPlacements should be for each spline?

Here's an example. Shows what I'm talking about

http://jsfiddle.net/9jgyd347/2/

Comment: What have your tried? Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle? Spline will go over the top of column if you have proper data for series - http://jsfiddle.net/t89bcnts/

Comment: Section (1) of this answer may be of help, if I understand the question properly:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356456/splines-with-grouped-columns-highcharts/20378899#20378899